# Overloading the `=` operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand overloading operators in c++. I've written some code below trying to overload the `=` operator. However, it doesn't work correctly and I am wondering why now.

I've followed the example that is provided here for the `+` operator.

[Operators Overloading in C++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    int id;
    string name;

public:
    Test(): id(0), name(""){

    }

    Test(int id, string name): id(id), name(name) {

    }

    void print() {
        cout << id << ":" << name << endl;

    }
    Test operator=( Test &other) {

        Test test;
        cout << "Assignment running" << endl;

        test.id =other.id;
        test.name =other.name;

        return test;

    }
};

int main() {

    Test test1(10, "Mike");
    cout << "Print Test1" << endl;
    test1.print();

    Test test2;

    test2.operator=(test1);
    cout << "Print Test2" << endl;
    test2.print();


    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: `test2.operator=(test1);` the whole point of overloading an operator is so you can call it like `test2 = test1` and not like a function-call...

Comment: You didn't consider looking at the example of overloading the assignment operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Since you're in discovery mode, note how `operator=` is not quite synonymous to a constructor with the same parameter type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by thinking about what semantics you expect. Since the whole point of overloading operators is that you can use the same syntax as built-in operators, replace

```
test2.operator=(test1);
```

with

```
test2 = test1;
```

- First, what do you expect to happen to test1 in this expression? Should it change?

  Hint: the answer is *no*, so the right-hand-side parameter should be passed by `const` reference.
- Secondly, what do you expect to happen to test2 in this expression? Should it change?

  Yes, of course it should change, you're assigning to it. So, the left-hand-side argument should be modified by your code. Note that in a member operator, the left-hand side is `this`.

So, we know we should at least change your code to take the right-hand-side parameter by const reference, and that it ought to modify `this` rather than leaving it untouched while assigning to a temporary.

Further, the canonical forms of all these operators are well-known and documented. For example, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator)

```
Test& operator=(const Test &other) {
    cout << "Assignment running" << endl;

    this->id =other.id;
    this->name =other.name;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: why do you have to pass other by reference and not by value? both ways work.

Comment: Passing the RHS by value is also semantically fine, but could be expensive for large objects, and there's no real benefit. In this case, it includes copying a string, which likely involves a dynamic allocation and subsequent deallocation. That's a relatively expensive operation, and one that can fail if you're out of memory.

Comment: Passing by value and then moving does have its advantages.  Especially when the move operation is noexcept.

Comment: True, but then I should explain the missing move assignment too, and that seemed like more than OP needs at this stage.

Answer (score 4):

`operator=`, by standard, should *modify* `this`, and return a reference to `*this` (in order to allow for compound assignments):

```
Test& operator=(const Test& other) {
    cout << "Assignment running" << endl;

    this->id = other.id;
    this->name = other.name;

    return *this;
}
```

Note that I'm also passing `other` as `const`. Your version does not modify `this`, which will have surprising effects.

Answer (score 3):

Because unlike `+`, `=` needs to modify the object in question, rather than a temporary variable that you then return.

```
Test& operator=(const Test &other) {

    cout << "Assignment running" << endl;

    id =other.id;
    name =other.name;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Technically, it doesn't have to modify the object in question, that's why the compiler accepted the code in the question. But it clearly was the intent.